# How do I fill the PBN\ part in a Flight Plan Form?

Tags: icao, ifr-navigation, flight-plans, rnav

Flight Plan Form Section 10 is the "Equipment" section, where one input whatever navigation or communication equipment on board. In addition, Section 18 is the "Other information" section, where you can add any supplemental information, some of it in relation to the aforementioned "Equipment" section.
[image]
My aircraft has every RNAV\RNP capabilities with indicators 1 through 10 (RNAV/RNP 10, RNAV 5, RNP 4, RNAV 2, RNAV/RNP 1). I need to use the "PBN\" indicator to detail PBN equipment capabilities. My question is how exactly?

In my case, should I file PBN\A1B2B4C2D2L1O2S1? Is it over the character limit? Is it actually necessary? Does it make sense?

Comment: [This document](https://www.icao.int/safety/FITS/DocumentLibrary/FITS-Library/Guidance_Item%2010_18.pdf) provides the rules to limit the number of indicators, page 2: *Filing Navigation Capability (Item 10 and Item 18 PBN/)*"

Comment: Great info. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 8 items selected, and the max allowed is 8. There is [guidance material from ICAO](https://www.icao.int/safety/FITS/DocumentLibrary/FITS-Library/Guidance_Item%2010_18.pdf) with steps to follow on how to get down to the 8 (in case you exceed it in the future). Right now you're fine.

For example:

> If having applied the guidance provided in Step 3 there are still more than 8 PBN codes remaining:
>
> > - Identify the capabilities considered to be the least relevant to the flight;
> > - Insert them under Item 18 within the NAV/ element;
> > - Insert the letter 'Z' in Item 10a.
>
> For example, the codes relating to long range Oceanic capabilities (A1, L1) will not be a priority if the flight will take place entirely within European continental airspace. Inclusion of an RNP APCH capability will not be a priority if none of the destination or alternate aerodromes provide such a procedure.